# When do AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem status change?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avplayer

I am working on a music player plugin in flutter using `AVFoundation` and I want to create a uniform interface on iOS and Android.

I want to capture errors that might be thrown by `AVPlayer` when, for example, the given `AVPlayerItem` is invalid (contains a `URL` of file which is unsupported, like a `png` file).

I would expect the `AVPlayer.replace()` to throw exception or change in status of `AVPlayerItem` or `AVPlayer` or at least some relevant notification on the `NSNotificationCeter`. I tried listening/observing all of them, but none of them reported any kind of error. In fact, the `AVPlayer` reported "ready-to-play" state.

```
    mediaPlayer = AVPlayer();
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "image", ofType: "png")!))

    playerItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status), options: [.old, .new], context: &playerItemContext)
    mediaPlayer?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.status), options: [.old, .new], context: &mediaPlayerContext)

    mediaPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem); // this changes player status to - "ready-to-play"
    mediaPlayer?.play() // this does not report anything
```

I am an android developer and can't understand how `AVPlayer` works. How can I achieve this?

Note:I can't use `AVAudioPlayer` because documentation says it shouldn't be used when playing music from the network or sources that may have latency.

```
self.mediaPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
self.mediaPlayer?.play()
```

Even this code doesn't generates error

Comment: This has nothing to do with AVPlayer. If the media player itself is nil, `self.mediaPlayer?.play()` does nothing at all. The line of code just aborts. So how could it possibly generate an error? That is not how Swift works.

Comment: You can observe `current item` and `error` property of avplayer

Comment: @matt the question has been edited .

Answer (score 2):

```
private func addObserverPlayerItem()
    {
        if let playerItem = self.player?.currentItem{
            playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options: .new, context: nil)
            playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: .new, context: nil)
            playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferFull", options: .new, context: nil)
            playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: [.new], context: nil)
            self.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.currentItem.status), options: [.new, .initial], context: nil)
            self.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.status), options: [.new, .initial], context: nil)
        }
    }

override public func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if object is AVPlayerItem {
            switch keyPath {

            case "loadedTimeRanges":

                let duration = self.currentItem?.totalBuffer() ?? 0
                let totalduration = currentItem?.asset.duration
                self.videoControll?.slider.bufferEndValue = totalduration?.seconds ?? 0
                self.videoControll?.slider.bufferStartValue = (duration) / (totalduration?.seconds ?? 1)
                print((duration) / (totalduration?.seconds ?? 1))

            case "playbackBufferEmpty":
                // Show loader
                self.activityIndicator?.startAnimating()

            case "playbackLikelyToKeepUp":
                // Hide loader
                self.activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()

            case "playbackBufferFull":
                // Hide loader
                self.activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
            case #keyPath(AVPlayer.currentItem.status):

                let newStatus: AVPlayerItem.Status
                if let newStatusAsNumber = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? NSNumber {
                    newStatus = AVPlayerItem.Status(rawValue: newStatusAsNumber.intValue)!
                } else {
                    newStatus = .unknown
                }
                if newStatus == .failed {
                    NSLog("SA Detected Error: \(String(describing: self.player?.currentItem?.error?.localizedDescription)), error: \(String(describing: self.player?.currentItem?.error))")
                }
            case #keyPath(AVPlayer.status):
                print()
            case .none:
                self.activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
            case .some(_):
                self.activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track the status of the player with help of [reasonforwaitingtoplay](/questions/tagged/reasonforwaitingtoplay) property of AVplayer.

> > When the value of timeControlStatus is AVPlayerTimeControlStatusWaitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate, this property describes why the player is currently waiting. It is nil otherwise.
> >             You can use the value of reasonForWaitingToPlay to show UI indicating the player's waiting state conditionally.
> >             This property is key value observable.
> >             Possible values are AVPlayerWaitingWithNoItemToPlayReason, AVPlayerWaitingWhileEvaluatingBufferingRateReason, and AVPlayerWaitingToMinimizeStallsReason.

If the value of this property is nil this means currently player is playing something.